# Is the following proof of $1/n < \epsilon $ correct?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

I'm trying to improve my proof writing skills and my mathematical instinct, so I tried to prove the following using contradiction :

"For every positive real number $\epsilon$, there exist a natural number $n$ : $\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$ "

I tried to prove that statement using contradiction :

Let's assume that there exist some positive real number $\epsilon$ that for each natural number $n$ we have that :

$$\frac{1}{n} \ge \epsilon $$

(I have rewrote the negation of my proposition :  $-P$ )

Then we have that $Inf({\frac{1}{n}}) = \epsilon$

On the other side we have that the sequence $\frac{1}{n}$ is convergent and it's limit tends to $0$ so :

$Inf ({\frac{1}{n}}) = 0$

Thus we have two infimum for the same set which is contradictory since infinimum is unique .

Is this proof correct ? If it's not where's it wrong ? How can I correct it ?

Thank's

Comment: How have you proved that $1/n$ converges to zero?

Comment: @user296602 the sequence is strictly decreasing and bounded so it converges and by simple limit calculation we have that when n tends to infinity then $\frac{1}{n}$ tends to zero .

Comment: So what exactly was that "simple limit calculation"? (I ask this because as written, I'm pretty much sure that your proof is circular...).

Comment: I remember that from highschool lessons on limits we have $\frac{1}{\infty} = 0$

Comment: Are you familiar with the Archimedean principle?

Comment: $\frac{1}{\infty} = 0$ is a nonsense expression. The fact that you need to know about is the Archimedean principle.

Comment: @Aweygan Yes I'm familiar but I don't know how to use it in this proof / context

Comment: You only technically have $\inf \frac{1}{n}\geq \epsilon$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews so $\epsilon$ is a just a lower bound ?

Comment: Of course, to know that $\frac{1}{n}$ is convergent to zero, you actually need a stronger theorem than what you are trying to prove - namely, that for all but finitely many $n$, $\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$. To prove this theorem, you need a special property of the real numbers, called the "archimedean property."

Comment: @ThomasAndrews We studied this theorem but I don't know how to use it in this contexte ?

Comment: If you are willing to assume that $1/n$ converges to zero, i.e. that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}=0$, then your proof could be much shorter: just apply the definition of a limit. Which brings up the issue raised in the very first comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof works, but you assume that $\text{inf}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = 0$, which is somewhat trivially equivalent to your result. To avoid that step, start from your assumption that $\frac{1}{n} \geq \varepsilon$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then notice that

If $\frac{1}{n} \geq \varepsilon$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $n \leq \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Then use the Archimedean Property, and you're done.

Comment: So I say something like that ? : Using the archimdean property we know that natural numbers are not bounded from the above while we have $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ as an upper bound which is contradictory ?

Comment: Yep. That's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here is possibly another approach to prove that for all $\epsilon >0$ you can find an $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Then choose a natural number $n$ such that $\frac{1}{\epsilon} < n$. Then $\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$.

(I don't know if this proof works for you. Writing a proof requires you to know exactly what you are allowed to assume.)